# How to ensure all variables have type declaration in Visual Studio TypeScript project

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

How to force, generate warnings, or some kind of log, for all variables whose type is not declared and cannot be inferred, in Visual Studio Community?

Comment: Take a look at compiler options. "noEmitOnError", "noImplicitAny", "noImplicitThis", etc. There is number of config properties, after setting them to true you will be able to see errors.

Comment: I try to setup up typescript compiler options on VS project file but no luck. The settings are just ignored or i don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: Have you tried adding _tsconfig.json_ and putting compiler options in it?

Comment: that functionality is only to VS Code, not the community version of VS.